# PDO CRUD Select Box not showing all Enum Values on EDIT

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have developed an application for creating job cards for computer repairs at my place of work.

I can submit data to my MySQL database and it works well. It saves the data and also sends an email to admin and the customer with the generated job card number which is an AUTOINCREMENT INT in MySQL. After saving the info to the database, you get directed back to a table that displays all the info saved (i am using JQuery Datadables with Bootstrap 5) Screenshot of Repairs Overview below:

[Repairs Overview Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmoKD.jpg)

When i click on the green VIEW | EDIT button, it takes me to the editrepairs.php page that populates the data for that particular job card as expected as per below image:

[Edit Repairs Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kooRG.jpg)

EXCEPT one issue... a few of the fields are  dropdowns. One of them in this example is "Current Status". The code i am using to retrieve the stored ENUM value from MySQL is the following:

```
 <?php
     //Select / Foreach function
    $smt = $db->prepare('select DISTINCT current_status From repairs WHERE job_number=:job_number');
      $smt->bindParam(':job_number',$job_number,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$smt->execute();
$data = $smt->fetchAll();
?>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Current Status</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<select name="current_status" id="current_status">
<?php foreach ($data as $row): ?>
    <option><?=$row["current_status"]?></option>
    
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>

    </div>
    </div>
```

The above displays ONLY the value that was saved during the adding of the job card. So when i need to change the status of the repair as i am working on the repair, i cannot as it is only showing 1 single value...

[No Other Options to Select Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHQ6X.jpg)

My Table name is **repairs**, my column name is **current_status** and the ENUM values are **Pending**, **In Progress**, **On Hold Spares Required**, **On Hold Other Fault** and **Repair Completed**

How can i display the SAVED status FIRST like it displays currently, but then also show the other values so i can change the status during the day/week/month as i am working on the repair?

I also tried the following code but it is doing the exact same thing i explained above.

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Current Status</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<select name="current_status" id="current_status" class="form-control input-sm">
    <?php

              $result = $db->query("SELECT current_status FROM repairs WHERE job_number = $job_number");
              foreach($result as $options)
              {
                  echo '<option value="'.$options['current_status'].'"';
                  if($options['current_status']==$job_number)
                  {
                      echo ' selected';
                  }
                  echo '>'. $options['current_status'] . '</option>'."\n";
              }
     ?>
    </select>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Oh and the top of my page has require_once 'connection.php'; for connecting to my database.

Comment: when you fetch all the status which populates a select for initial create job, copy that same code into edit, then determine `selected` based upon current_status row value

Comment: Im not using any PHP to get the values during the adding of the job card. Its just a normal Bootstrap <select> .... </select> form field with hardcoded options that match MySQL values.

Comment: then do https://3v4l.org/brXN7, also you wont need to loop over it `$result = $db->query` should be fetchColumn etc, plus be wary of `job_number = $job_number` being open to SQL injection

Comment: That worked like a charm. Can you give me a link to read up about the procedure you demonstrated? $result = $db->query should be fetchColumn i have changed. Also can you give me some links as well where i can research the most secure way to do job_number = $job_number. I will post the answer to this question now as your comments has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the correct answer for my question is

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Current Status</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<select name="current_status" id="current_status">
    <option value="1" <?= $current_status === 'Pending' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Pending</option>
    <option value="2" <?= $current_status === 'In Progress' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>In Progress</option>
      <option value="3" <?= $current_status === 'On Hold Spares Required' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>On Hold Spares Required</option>
       <option value="3" <?= $current_status === 'On Hold Other Fault' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>On Hold Other Fault</option>
   </select>

    </div>
    </div>
```

From my understanding, ive learned from the comments of Lawrence that the operator

> **===** which means **Identical**

Returns true if $x is equal to $y, and they are of the same type.

The above displays the CURRENTLY selected value in MySQL databse PLUS allows me to choose the other options as well and it correctly saves it to the database when the update button is pressed.

PHP CODE ON TOP OF MY PAGE:

```
<?php
require_once 'connection.php';

  session_start();

  if(!isset($_SESSION['admin_login'])) //check unauthorize user not direct access in "admindashboard.php" page
  {
   header("location: index.php");  
  }

  if(isset($_SESSION['employee_login'])) //check employee login user not access in "admin_home.php" page
  {
   header("location: employeedashboard.php"); 
  }

  if(isset($_SESSION['tech_login'])) //check user login user not access in "admin_home.php" page
  {
   header("location: techdashboard.php");
  }
  
  if(isset($_SESSION['admin_login']))
  {
?>
<?php

if(isset($_REQUEST['update_id']))
{
 try
 {
  $job_number = $_REQUEST['update_id']; 
  $select_stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM repairs WHERE job_number =:job_number'); 
  $select_stmt->bindParam(':job_number',$job_number,PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $select_stmt->execute(); 
  $row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  extract($row);
 }
 catch(PDOException $e)
 {
  $e->getMessage();
 }
 
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['btn_update']))
{
 
                $job_number = $_REQUEST['job_number'];
                $date = $_REQUEST['date'];
                $client_full_name = filter_var($_REQUEST['client_full_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $client_email = filter_var($_REQUEST['client_email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
               $client_phone = filter_var($_REQUEST['client_phone'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $item_for_repair = filter_var($_REQUEST['item_for_repair'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $repair_description = filter_var($_REQUEST['repair_description'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $hardware_details = filter_var($_REQUEST['hardware_details'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $diagnostic_fee = filter_var($_REQUEST['diagnostic_fee'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $tech_assigned = filter_var($_REQUEST['tech_assigned'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $current_status = filter_var($_REQUEST['current_status'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $technician_notes = filter_var($_REQUEST['technician_notes'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $admin_notes = filter_var($_REQUEST['admin_notes'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $invoice_status = filter_var($_REQUEST['invoice_status'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
                $invoice_number = filter_var($_REQUEST['invoice_number'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  
  {
  try
  {
      
   if(!isset($errorMsg))
   {
       $update_stmt=$db->prepare('UPDATE repairs SET job_number=:job_number, date=:date, client_full_name=:client_full_name, client_email=:client_email, client_phone=:client_phone, item_for_repair=:item_for_repair, repair_description=:repair_description, hardware_details=:hardware_details, diagnostic_fee=:diagnostic_fee, tech_assigned=:tech_assigned, current_status=:current_status, technician_notes=:technician_notes, admin_notes=:admin_notes, invoice_status=:invoice_status, invoice_number=:invoice_number WHERE job_number=:job_number'); 

                $update_stmt->bindParam(':job_number', $job_number, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':date', $date);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':client_full_name', $client_full_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':client_email', $client_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':client_phone', $client_phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':item_for_repair', $item_for_repair, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':repair_description',$repair_description, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':hardware_details', $hardware_details, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':diagnostic_fee', $diagnostic_fee, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':tech_assigned', $tech_assigned, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':current_status', $current_status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':technician_notes', $technician_notes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':admin_notes', $admin_notes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':invoice_status', $invoice_status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $update_stmt->bindParam(':invoice_number', $invoice_number, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
     
    if($update_stmt->execute())
    {
     $updateMsg="Record Update Successfully. Refreshing in 3 seconds."; 
     header("refresh:3;repairs.php"); 
    }
   } 
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
   echo $e->getMessage();
  } 
 } 
}
?>
```

AND MY FORM (ON THE SAME PAGE)

```
 <!-- first row starts here -->
                         <?php
if(isset($errorMsg)){
?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>ERROR ! <?php echo $errorMsg; ?></strong>
    </div>
<?php
}
if(isset($updateMsg)){
?>
 <div class="alert alert-success">
  <strong>UPDATED ! <?php echo $updateMsg; ?></strong>
 </div>
<?php
}
?> 
<form method="post" name="form" id="form" class="form form-horizontal" action="">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Job Number</label>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <input type="text" name="job_number" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $job_number; ?>" readonly>
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date Repair Booked in</label>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" readonly>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Client Full Name</label>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <input type="text" name="client_full_name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $client_full_name; ?>">
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Client Email</label>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <input type="text" name="client_email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $client_email; ?>">
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Client Phone Number</label>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <input type="text" name="client_phone" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $client_phone; ?>">
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Item For Repair</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<select name="item_for_repair" id="item_for_repair">
    <option value="1" <?= $item_for_repair === 'Laptop' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Laptop</option>
    <option value="2" <?= $item_for_repair === 'Desktop' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Desktop</option>
    <option value="3" <?= $item_for_repair === 'Television' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Television</option>
    <option value="4" <?= $item_for_repair === 'Washing Machine' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Washing Machine</option>
    <option value="5" <?= $item_for_repair === 'Tumble Dryer' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Tumble Dryer</option>
    <option value="6" <?= $item_for_repair === 'Dishwasher' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Dishwasher</option>
    <option value="7" <?= $item_for_repair === 'Microwave' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Microwave</option>
    <option value="8" <?= $item_for_repair === 'Fridge' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Fridge</option>
    <option value="9" <?= $item_for_repair === 'Printer' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Printer</option>
    <option value="10" <?= $item_for_repair === 'Other' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Other</option>
</select>
    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Repair Description</label>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <input type="text" name="repair_description" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $repair_description; ?>">
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Hardware Details</label>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <input type="text" name="hardware_details" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $hardware_details; ?>">
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Diagnostic Fee</label>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <input type="text" name="diagnostic_fee" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $diagnostic_fee; ?>">
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Technician Assigned</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<select name="tech_assigned" id="tech_assigned">
    <option value="1" <?= $tech_assigned === 'Brendon' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Brendon</option>
    <option value="2" <?= $tech_assigned === 'Gabriel' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Gabriel</option>
    <option value="3" <?= $tech_assigned === 'Jami' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Jami</option>
    <option value="4" <?= $tech_assigned === 'Lee-Roy' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Lee-Roy</option>
    <option value="5" <?= $tech_assigned === 'Conrad' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Conrad</option>
    <option value="6" <?= $tech_assigned === 'Tapiwa' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Tapiwa</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Current Status</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<select name="current_status" id="current_status">
    <option value="1" <?= $current_status === 'Pending' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Pending</option>
    <option value="2" <?= $current_status === 'In Progress' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>In Progress</option>
      <option value="3" <?= $current_status === 'On Hold Spares Required' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>On Hold Spares Required</option>
       <option value="3" <?= $current_status === 'On Hold Other Fault' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>On Hold Other Fault</option>
   </select>

    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Technician Notes</label>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <input type="text" name="technician_notes" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $technician_notes; ?>">
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Admin Notes</label>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <input type="text" name="admin_notes" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $admin_notes; ?>">
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Invoice Status</label>
<div class="col-sm-12">
<select name="invoice_status" id="invoice_status">
    <option value="1" <?= $invoice_status === 'Client Not Invoiced Yet' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Client Not Invoiced Yet</option>
    <option value="2" <?= $invoice_status === 'Client Invoiced' ? 'selected' : '' ?>>Client Invoiced</option>
   </select>

    </div>
    </div>
  <div class="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Invoice Number</label>
 <div class="col-sm-12">
 <input type="text" name="invoice_number" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $invoice_number; ?>">
 </div>
 </div>
      
 <div class="form-group">
 <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9 m-t-15">
 <input type="submit" name="btn_update" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update">
  <a href="repairs.php" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
 </div>
 </div>
   </form>
```

I am using this on a LOCAL machine with NO internet connection, so i am aware of some security issues in my code, but with no outside access to the app, i dont mind slipping up on the security. But i will work on this and come back and post my new code here with updated PDO/PHP security measures